# Having an issueif else and if else statements.

Tags: java, boolean

I'm really new to java (third week of class), but I've been trying to work on this code for hours and I just can't seem to find an answer to what I'm doing. javac tells me I only have three errors, but I'm wondering if there's more than that.
Here's my code, and I know my average section still needs work but i just cant figure out what's going on with the middle section of if and else statements. Sorry if this is really dumb, and im sure my syntax is all over the place:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program1
{
    static public void main( String args [ ] )
    {
        int grade;
        int A,B,C,D,F;

        A = 0;
        B = 0;
        C = 0;
        D = 0;
        F = 0;

        System.out.println( "***************  Grade Computer *************");

        // ********************** //
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Students First Name: ");
        String fname = kbd.next( );
        System.out.println("Enter Students Middle Initial: ");
        String mi = kbd.next( );
        System.out.println("Enter Students Last Name: "); 
        String lname = kbd.next( );
        System.out.println("Enter First Exam Grade: ");
        int firstexam = kbd.nextInt( );
        System.out.println("Enter Second Exam Grade: ");
        int secondexam = kbd.nextInt( );
        System.out.println("Enter Third Exam Grade: ");
        int thirdexam = kbd.nextInt( );
        System.out.println("Was the bonus done? [yes/no] : ");
        boolean b = kbd.nextBoolean( );

        boolean yes = true;
        boolean no = false;

        // *********************** //

        if(true)
        {
            {
                if((firstexam >= (secondexam * 0.60 ) ) & (firstexam >= (thirdexam * 0.80 )));
                {
                    System.out.println(firstexam);
                }
                else if((secondexam * 0.60) >= (thirdexam * 0.80));
                {
                    System.out.println(secondexam * 0.60);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(thirdexam * 0.80);
                }
            }

            if(true)
            {
                if((secondexam >= firstexam) & ((thirdexam * 0.80) >= secondexam));
                {
                    if(secondexam >= (thirdexam * 0.80));
                    {
                        System.out.println(secondexam);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(thirdexam * 0.80);
                }
            }

            else {
                System.out.println(firstexam);
                System.out.println(secondexam);
                System.out.println(thirdexam);
            }
        }

        // ********************** //

        System.out.println(" **********Grade Summary********** ");
        double average = calcAverage(firstexam, secondexam, thirdexam);
        System.out.println("Grade Report For: " + fname);
        if (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Bonus was done so grades are adjusted if appropriate.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Bonus was not done.");
        }
        System.out.println("Exam 1: " + firstexam);
        System.out.println("Exam 2: " + secondexam);
        System.out.println("Exam 3: " + thirdexam);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        determineGrade(average);
    }

    public static double calcAverage(int firstexam, int secondexam, int thirdexam) 
    {
        double average = (firstexam + secondexam + thirdexam) / 3.0;
        return average;

    }

    public static void determineGrade(double average)
    {
        if (average>90)
        {
            System.out.println("Grade: A");
        }
        else if (average>=80)
        {
            System.out.println("Grade: B");
        }
        else if (average>=70)
        {
            System.out.println("Grade: C");
        }
        else if (average>=60)
        {
            System.out.println("Grade: D");
        }
        else if (average<60)
        {
            System.out.println("Grade: F");
        }

    }

    // ************** //

}
```

Comment: Remove the dead codes...!! No use of else, when using if(true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((firstexam >= (secondexam * 0.60 ) ) & (firstexam >= (thirdexam * 0.80 )))   (;)
```

The `;` shouldn't be here.

**Difference between `&` and `&&` :**

& <-- verifies both operands
&& <-- stops evaluating if the first operand evaluates to false since the result will be false

`(x != 0) & (1/x > 1)` <-- this means evaluate `(x != 0)` then evaluate `(1/x > 1)` then do the &. the problem is that for x=0 this will throw an exception.

`(x != 0) && (1/x > 1)` <-- this means evaluate `(x != 0)` and only if this is true then evaluate `(1/x > 1)` so if you have x=0 then this is perfectly safe and won't throw any exception if (x != 0) evaluates to false the whole thing directly evaluates to false without evaluating the `(1/x > 1)`.

**An other thing :**

```
if(true)
        {
            {
```

This should be deleted because it just adds more code , it will be executed every time so no need to add it.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements having `;`  in the end

```
    if((firstexam >= (secondexam * 0.60 ) ) & (firstexam >= (thirdexam * 0.80 )));
```

They are considering as statements and proceeding further.

Remove all of them in the end of each statement.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the colon the end of the if statement you also should keep in mind that if you use

```
               if(true){
               }else{
               }
```

The else statement will never execute cos the if will always be true, so you should be using  the yes/no variables as flags for your if statement instead of the "true" itself.

If your statements inside the if should always be executed then you don't need the conditions at all.